# Assessing damage after rm -Rf

Tags: linux

Well, you know all those warnings about rm -rf? :) I managed to use it to delete quite number of files unknowingly.

I was inside directory:

```
/media/storage/vod
```

And I issued command:

```
sudo rm -R *.QTFS series/*
```

I was trying to remove *.QTFS files inside dir series. After seeing empty series dir I realized that command took two commands delete *.QTFS and delete series/*

What I would like to know, is where did *.QTFS delete happened recursively inside my current dir?

I'm trying to assess damage done. So what did I do ? :(

Should I be worried of removing anything else besides series/* ?

Did recursive rm traverse up the directory tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to be concerned. The rm command only erased all QTFS and everything under the series folder, nothing else.

Comment: What should I have done instead? to delete only QTFS files? sudo rm -R *.QTFS series ? This would do the same correct?

Comment: You should have used `sudo rm -rf series/*.QTFS`

Comment: Since it is the shell that expands wildcards, `sudo rm -rf series/*.QTFS` only deletes files directly in `series` directory. If you want a recursive deletion of .QTFS files under `series` directory, you need a bit of trickery: `find -print0 series -name '*.QTFS' | xargs -0 rm`. Here we first make a list of files with `fond` utility, and then pass the list to `rm` with `xargs` utility. `-print0` / `-0` ensure that filenames with spaces work correctly too.